# cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'GPXType'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gpx

I have done some research on that issue , but I have not found anything similar just yet.

I am using iOS GPX framework to draw the path on map using GPX file. I have import iOS GPX.framework on my project. but I have face an issue.

Please Guide me, If anyone has any advice...

[image]

Comment: probably duplicate: [“Cannot find interface declaration for NSObject”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994911/cannot-find-interface-declaration-for-nsobject)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I have check already that link But my issue not solved please guide me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem

I have import  **#import < UIKit/UIKit.h>** and change my Xcode 6 Architectures **$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)**.

Thanks so much Guys.

Answer (score 53):

Just modify the header file, add this line on top of the file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Seems they thought that you will have a `PCH` file, where Foundation and UIKit will be imported, but Xcode 6 removed PCH default support, so the problem came. (See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034161/did-the-way-how-to-globally-import-files-change-in-xcode-6-ios-8/27034234#27034234))

Comment: Saved my life dude

Comment: @KeghamK. barevner Hayastanic :)

Comment: @I0gg3r Hayes doun? :D Armenian from Armenia saved an Armenian from Egypt (Y) Shad shad shnorhagalem akhber jan

Comment: आभारी आहे भावा, वेळ वाचवलास!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported the header file #import  ...

When compiling for both iOS and OsX, I had similar issue that I have resolved by importing TargetConditionals.h. The final thing looks like this:

```
#import <TargetConditionals.h>

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#elif TARGET_OS_MAC

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#endif



@interface MyClass : NSObject

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE

// Define UIKit methods

#elif TARGET_OS_MAC

// Define Cocoa methods

#endif

- (void)reloadRegisteredComponents;


@end
```