# Navigate to another ViewController from Swift Controller to Objective C controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im looking for a solution to navigate to a viewcontroller in objective-C from a Swift viewcontroller.

Im using storybord with a navigation controller.

My Swift 2.0 code are as follows:

```
if ((user) != nil) {
                    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "You are now Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alert.show()

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Menu")
                        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })

                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alert.show()
                }
            })
        }
```

The Viewcontroller in Objective-C i want to present are named : CategoriesController

Comment: what exactly is your question / problem? There is no problem whatsoever transitioning to a viewcontroller written in the other language.

Comment: When im adding this code :

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Menu")
self.presentViewController(CategoriesController, animated: true, completion: nil)

in the Swift file to present the "CategoriesController" im getting the error message :

"Use of unresolved identifier 'CategoriesController'"

Comment: Im trying to navigate from at viewcontroller in Swift from Storyboard to a viewcontroller in Objective-C that are not in my Storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

to navigate from swiftcontroller to objective-c controller the code is same but only you have to import objective c file in bridging-header .
for adding bridge-header you can see tutorial over here [Create bridge file](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/)

see code i have used in my project is same . i just import "ObjectiveViewController.h" in bridge header file

```
 let mycards = ObjectiveViewController(nibName:"ObjectiveViewController", bundle : nil)
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mycards, animated: true) and its working
```

Comment: The code you gave me works with no errors. But now after "#import CategoriesController.h" in the Bridging-Header.h, this causes fault in
other Objective-C files.
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <ParseTwitterUtils/ParseTwitterUtils.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import "CategoriesController.h"

Comment: Fault message "Cannot find interface decleration for 'ControlBase', superclass of 'FilterBaseController'

Comment: have you import all `#import <Parse/Parse.h> #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> #import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h> #import <ParseTwitterUtils/ParseTwitterUtils.h> #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> #import <Bolts/Bolts.h> #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h> #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h> #import "CategoriesController.h"` in headre file?

Comment: Yes. It all works fine until i added the "#import "CategoriesController.h" file in the Bridging-header.h file. After that i get the fault message.

Comment: Add this to your header:
`#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Comment: I have the "#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>" in the 'CategoriesController.h'. Is it there you mean ?

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994911/cannot-find-interface-declaration-for-nsobject (second answer)

Comment: Solved the issue. The Bridging-Header was not added to my Build Setting.

Comment: How can this be programmed in Swift 2.0 : CategoriesController *mainViewController = [[CategoriesController alloc] init];
    [mainViewController setConfigDictionary:_configDictionary];

    [self.navigationController initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

Comment: if self is not have init with navigation controller 
`let mycards = CategoriesController(nibName:"CategoriesController", bundle : nil)
self.presentViewController(UINavigationController(rootViewController: mycards), animated: true, completion: nil)`
and if self is init view navigation controller then 
`let mycards = CategoriesController(nibName:"CategoriesController", bundle : nil)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mycards, animated: true)`

Comment: I solved the issue. I made a new viewcontroller in Storyboard and imbedded in a navigation controller. Then i named the new viewcontroller 'CategoriesController'. Then im using this code to show the main viewcontroller : let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CategoriesController")
                        self.showViewController(viewController, sender: true)

Answer (score 0):

So suppose
I have a viewcontroller MemberShipVC.h and .m written in objective C

I have a another viewcontroller CertifiedVC.swift written in swift

so here I want to navigate in MemberShipVC from CertifiedVC.swift

Step 1- import "MemberShipVC.h" in YourApp-Bridging-Header.h file

Step 2- on any action in CertifiedVC.swift put below line

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mVC : MemberShipVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MemberShipVC") as! MemberShipVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mVC, animated: true)
```

Thats all you need to do.
Hope this helps.